# Apply IF to range of cells in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to have the following code applied to cells 19:500 in Column I. If I remove the set Range line of code, I19 updates properly but Once i add the range, the following code stops working? Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
Sub Status_Load()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Range As Range
    Dim Today As Date
    With Sheet1

        Set Range = .Range("I19:I500")

        For Each Cell In Range
            If Range("N19").Value = Empty Then Exit Sub

            If Range("O19").Value <> Month(Today) Then
                Range("I19").Value = "Carried"
            ElseIf Range("S19").Value <> "" Then
                Range("I19").Value = "Closed"
            Else: Range("I19").Value = "Open"
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. bad practice to name variables the same as items in VBA.  Do not name a variable, `Range` or `Today`. 2. Add a `.` in front of the `Range()` to use the same sheet.  3.  You loop is not doing anything different.  It will only affect row `19` as all the ranges are hard coded and do not use the reference from the `For`.

Comment: The reason it errored was you were using `Range` as a variable and when you did not use `.` in front it assumed you wanted to use the variable and the variable does not use `("A1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular `For...Next` loop and loop the rows:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 19 to 500
    If IsEmpty(.Range("N" & i).Value) Then Exit Sub

    If .Range("O" & i).Value <> Month(Date) Then
        .Range("I" & i).Value = "Carried"
    ElseIf .Range("S" & i).Value <> "" Then
        .Range("I" & i).Value = "Closed"
    Else
        .Range("I" & i).Value = "Open"
    End If
Next
```

Side notes (as mentioned in comments):

- `Dim Range As Range`: **bad idea**. Don't reuse members of the object model as variable names.
- If you don't add the `.` in front of each `Range` call within the loop, then you're *not* actually referencing the `With Sheet1`.
- `Dim Today As Date`. Perhaps you didn't include the line in your question `Today = Date`? In any case, you can just drop that variable and use `Date` directly, i.e. `Month(Today)` --> `Month(Date)`.

**EDIT**:

As discussed in the comments, you may just be able to use a formula here and avoid VBA:

```
=IF(S66<>"","Closed",IF(AND(O66<>"",OR(MONTH(O66)<>MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(O66)<>YEAR(TODAY()))),"Carried",IF(N66<>"","Open","")))
```

Comment: PLEASE address the declarations, using the same as the items.

Comment: @ScottCraner - sure. `Today` is fine though as a variable name, right?

Comment: Thanks so much! i just copied it over but it's only returning a value of carried for all cells even those that should be closed/opened? If the following lines are also true will the first line trump the others?

Comment: If the first line condition is true, then none of the others will be evaluated, correct. That's how `ElseIf` and `Else` work. Maybe explain your logic a bit more?

Comment: I'm trying to assign a status to a risk in a log. Column N contains the description and when populated would move status to open. Column O contains the date identified and once the current month date is no longer equal to the month/year the risk was identified the status would change to carried. Finally Column S contains the resolution date and when populated would move the status to closed.

Comment: You could probably do this with a formula, no VBA needed.

Comment: I tried with Nested Ifs but couldn't figure it out.. any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have your data in front of me but try `=IF(N19<>"","Open",IF(AND(MONTH(O19)<>MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(O19)<>YEAR(TODAY())),"Carried",IF(S19<>"","Closed","")))`.

Comment: Thanks!! I plugged in that formula and after slightly shifting the conditions [ =IF(S66<>"","Closed",IF(OR(MONTH(O66)<>MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(O66)<>YEAR(TODAY())),"Carried",IF(N66<>"","Open",""))) ] it worked! however, blank cells are assigning to carried rather than blank. I believe this is because the second the condition evaluates as true because the date identified date in column O is blank and therefore not equal to today's month/year date . I think adding an additional condition to the OR portion may correct this?> maybe an ISBLANK crriteria? Really appreciate your help with this!!

Comment: Try `=IF(S66<>"","Closed",IF(AND(O66<>"",OR(MONTH(O66)<>MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(O66)<>YEAR(TODAY()))),"Carried",IF(N66<>"","Open","")))`.